# Force Facebook to preview image from original link, not server side redirect

Tags: facebook, facebook-sharer

I hope someone can help - please bear with the explanation!  I have 5 years of gallery photos, published here:  https://www.girlsfly2.ca/past_events.html (redirects to https://www.girlsfly2.ca/past_events_2016.html).

Two main plugins are implemented - Packery bin-packs the photos into a gallery arrangement, LightGallery allows for individual slide-show and Facebook (and other social media) share.

The desired behavior is that a visitor is able to share a photo they like on their FB timeline - a preview of that specific photo, along with whatever comments they choose to make.  Then, if one of their friends is interested by the photo, they can click on the photo - which is actually a link - and visit the source.

The initial problem I had was that FB would preview the source page, and not the individual photo.  This is because the LG plugin uses a hash plugin to generate a "page" for sharing.  The developer suggested a workaround was to pass an html link for each photo through the plugin, which worked and the photo previewed correctly.

This created a new problem in that when one clicked on the return link from FB one landed on the individual photo, with no way to navigate back to the main gallery since nothing else was loaded. This creates a frustration for the user, if they wanted to find out what the photo, and our initiative is all about.

The developer told me what I wanted was only possible if I created a complete HTML page for each photo (approximately 400 of them!).  I had the bright idea to use server-side redirects in the interim - so that when one clicked on the image link it would redirect to the main gallery page of that particular year.

When I coded 2016 I tested functionality several times before implementing the redirects, and even though I didn't share each and every photo, FB seems to have cached the original links, not the redirects for all the photos.

I tackled 2013 and 2012 next but in this case the redirects were implemented in advance of publishing the respective pages and I discovered that FB is now previewing a default photo for all shares from each respective gallery.  This is not ideal!  I instantly had this problem when I created a batch folder redirect in 2016 which went away when I did individual redirects for all 207 photos, perhaps because some individual links were already cached.

Last night I played around with the FB scrape tool and disabled the 2013 redirects while I tested this.  I'm wondering if I encourage FB to cache the individual photo links and then re-implement the server-side redirects if that will work?

Also, this is a very time consuming and cumbersome fix - and I'm guessing it won't be permanent either.  Surely there is a better way through coding?

**The bottom line question:**  *Is there a way to force FB to preview the original html link, instead of it pinging the server, detecting the redirect and displaying a default image from the redirect gallery page?*

*Note that 2015 photos have not been redirected!*  The undesired preview behavior can be seen on the 2012 page, and at the time of writing the desired preview behavior is happening on the 2016 photos even the the coding style for both pages is the same.  Also 2014 is not yet published so for the moment will yield a 404.

Sorry for the long explanation - I didn't see a way to shorten it.  I really hope someone can help with this!

Comment: Facebook follows redirects. The reason for that is if there is a redirect the user will be redirected. And Facebook wants to display what the user will see

Comment: So why do the 2016 photos continue to work (for now)?  I just spent the better part of an hour manually scraping all 55 photos for 2013 and then re-implemented the redirects - all of which gets rid of the main gallery page preview for the 2013 photos, but the individual image doesn't show on the FB timeline - just a big white box.  As soon as I comment out the redirects the image previews properly.

Surely there must be a way around this?!

Comment: Use the debugger at https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/ to see what Facebook is doing

Comment: Update - ok I just double checked 2016 and only the images that have been shared a few times "stick".

Comment: Yes I've tried that as you can see from my details.  How do I control the behavior to achieve this:  **The bottom line question:** Is there a way to force FB to preview the original html link, instead of it pinging the server, detecting the redirect and displaying a default image from the redirect gallery page?

Comment: No there is not. As I said. Facebook want to show the preview of the URL that the user will see. If there is a redirect Facebook will follow it

Comment: Facebook caches results, and will also update them from time to time. So what you see "working" now, is most likely only working by accident. You need to either implement an exception from the server-side redirect (FB scraper can be recognized by its User-Agent), or do it client-side (via JavaScript, which the FB scraper does not care about.)

Comment: Hi @CBroe, thank you for your comments, yes, after extensive testing and scraping I discovered that the redirect solution wasn't going to work.  For now I have published our galleries and set the FB OG tags to present the desired image and message from each page.  www.girlsfly2.ca/past_events.html

I was wondering if you could explain your two suggestions?  I'm not very good with JS (yet) but may have someone that could help if I knew what to ask for.  Perhaps I could do the first suggestion myself but need a bit of clarity to understand what is needed?

Thanks for responding with options!